# Posting escaped characters in Slack

Tags: slack

I'm trying to type the characters "&amp;" in a Slack chat (I'm teaching a basic web design course), but Slack recursively converts the escaped characters into "&": &, &amp; and &amp;amp; all appear exactly the same when posting, how can I show them?

Comment: Hi @user3901018 When I test posting those they all show verbatim as I typed them in. Are you using the browser or web client?

Comment: @JohnC I was using the official android app. It looks ok in the web client, without anything escaped.